# При изменении width, теряет форму height 100vh?

Tags: html, css, height, width

когда блоку выдаю height: calc(100vh - 50px); то все равботает, но если добавлю туда и width 650px; к этому же блоку, то творится бред, по высоте блок становится примерно по центру высоты, не понимаю как такое исправить (чисто для телефонов, у пк все нормально отображается)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    background: #0ff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/m-messages.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Black+Ops+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>VKT Friends</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">


            


        </div>

        <?php
            include "nav/nav.php"
        ?>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: добавьте в вопрос ваш код

Comment: Добавил код, заранее спасибо

Comment: у меня отображается правильно в firefox, какой браузер используете?

Comment: Я использую сейчас Opera GX, на смартфоне установлен Chrome, он отображает неисправно, так же как и на скрине, (на скрине показан как будет отображаться страничка для телефона), и поэтому не понимаю... Почему на ПК все правильно, а на Телефонах - нет

Comment: а на stackoverflow код, который вы добавили в инспекторе тоже отображается неправильно? нажмите выполнить код > на всю страницу > инспектор

Comment: Не могу точно сказать, так как у меня в коде использован height: 100vh; - он, как я понимаю, разтягивает див по всей высоте экрана, а я не знаю какая высота отображения на этом форуме

Comment: вы ж сами сказали, высота экрана, она у вас не поменялась, выберите только "на всю страницу"

Comment: Да.. У меня почему то он онотбражается нормально, как и задуманно было, но я не понимаю, почему тогда тот код, который у меня на компьютере открыт, отображается совсем не так, как надо..

Comment: почистите кеш браузера, перезапустите php сервер

Comment: Не помогло.....

Comment: возможно как то nav.php влияет на отображение, тут то он не запускается

Comment: Я проверял, убирал, все равно так же все.. И даже пробовал html расширение файла сделать

Comment: попробуйте еще убрать <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Comment: Даааа, получилось)) Большое спасибо!))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо content="width=device-width" берет вашу заданную ширину 650px, масштабирует до ширины экрана девайса и заодно пропорционально  масштабирует высоту